# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError exception while the field is defined

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, eclipse-wtp

I'm working on a web application for Apache Tomcat.
I'm using a class called Location in which i defined a field called ipAddresses. Here it is:

```
package com.maxmind.geoip;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;

public class Location {
private final static double EARTH_DIAMETER = 2 * 6378.2;
private final static double PI = 3.14159265;
private final static double RAD_CONVERT = PI / 180;

public Set<String> ipAddresses;
public String countryCode;
public String countryName;
public String region;
public String city;
public String postalCode;
public float latitude;
public float longitude;
public int dma_code;
public int area_code;
public int metro_code;

public Location() {
    ipAddresses = new HashSet<String>();
}
...
}
```

However, after deploying the webapp to the server (war file) and trying to run the servlet that is using this class in it, i'm getting the exception **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError** for **ipAddresses**.

Moreover, when trying to debug it (Eclipse), when i reach a place where **Location loc = new Location()** is called, two weird things happen:

1. The constructor i coded isn't called, the debugger won't step into it, instead the program counter arrow is shown on on of the imports of in the Location.java file.
2. After "returning" from the **Location loc = new Location()** call, when i'm viewing the object's content the field actually does not exist.
3. The source file that was deployed with the jar file does include this field.

I have tried many things:

- cleaning and building the project and redeploying it.
- cleaning the server's working directory, both manual and by using Eclipse.
- changing the working directory of the server, in Eclipse.
- re-installing the server in Eclipse.
- re-installing Tomcat entirely, three times and to different locations!

I'm pretty stuck. What could it be?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms indicate that you have the `com.maxmind.geoip.Location` class in some JAR in the `JRE/lib` or `JRE/lib/ext` or any other Eclipse/Tomcat-independent classpath location which will always have precedence in classloading over the WAR's classes.

Examining the `loc.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` after you construct it should give insights about where it is *actually* been loaded from.

Comment: Well, it did give me the insight i needed. From some unclear reason there was some jar in the JRE/lib/ext folder that wasn't supposed to be there and held some older implementation of this class. Deleting it solved my case. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the field at all? Are there any references to it?. It is entirely possible that Eclipse is optimising it away.

In `Windows->Preferences->Java->Compiler`, there is a setting: `Preserve unused (never read) local variables`. Is this checked? If not, check it and try again.

Comment: It is used for sure. The exception is raised in the place where it is referenced.